# wordpress: get_header() not working in template file makes page white

Tags: wordpress

When I create a template in WordPress theme.

```
 <?php
/*
  Template Name: homepage
 */
get_header();
?>
```

it makes page blank, in source all DOMs load, but does not show. when remove get_header(); then it show. the bellow is header.php

```
<?php

/**
 * The template for displaying the header
 *
 * Displays all of the head element and everything up until the "site-content" div.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
$lan = get_bloginfo('language');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js" <?php
                                                    if ($lan == 'dr') {
                                                      echo 'dir="rtl"';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>>

<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(array($lan)); ?>>
    <!-- Page Loader-->
    <div id="page-loader">
        <div class="page-loader-logo">
            <div class="brand">
                <div class="brand__name"><img src="<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>" alt="" width="135" height="47" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-loader-body">
            <div id="loadingProgressG">
                <div class="loadingProgressG" id="loadingProgressG_1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page-->
    <div class="page">
        <!-- Page Header-->
        <header class="page-header section">
            <!-- RD Navbar-->
            <div class="rd-navbar-wrap">
                <nav class="rd-navbar rd-navbar-creative" data-layout="rd-navbar-fixed" data-sm-layout="rd-navbar-fixed" data-sm-device-layout="rd-navbar-fixed" data-md-layout="rd-navbar-fullwidth" data-md-device-layout="rd-navbar-fixed" data-lg-device-layout="rd-navbar-fullwidth"
                    data-lg-layout="rd-navbar-fullwidth" data-stick-up-clone="false" data-md-stick-up-offset="150px" data-lg-stick-up-offset="60px" data-md-stick-up="true" data-lg-stick-up="true">
                    <div class="rd-navbar-aside-outer rd-navbar-content-outer">
                        <div class="rd-navbar-content__toggle rd-navbar-fullwidth--hidden" data-rd-navbar-toggle=".rd-navbar-content"><span></span></div>
                        <div class="rd-navbar-aside rd-navbar-content">
                            <div class="rd-navbar-aside__item">
                                <ul class="rd-navbar-items-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="unit unit-spacing-xxs unit-horizontal">
                                            <div class="unit__left"><span class="icon icon-sm icon-primary fl-bigmug-line-trophy55"></span></div>
                                            <div class="unit__body">
                                                <p>Number #1 Supplier in Europe</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="unit unit-spacing-xxs unit-horizontal">
                                            <div class="unit__left"><span class="icon icon-sm icon-primary fl-bigmug-line-circular220"></span></div>
                                            <div class="unit__body">
                                                <p>Certified ISO 9001:2008</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rd-navbar-aside__item">
                                <ul class="rd-navbar-items-list">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="unit unit-spacing-xxs unit-horizontal">
                                            <div class="unit__left"><span class="text-primary">Phone:</span></div>
                                            <div class="unit__body"><a href="callto:#">+1 (409) 987–5874</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rd-navbar-main-outer">
                        <div class="rd-navbar-main">
                            <!-- RD Navbar Panel -->
                            <div class="rd-navbar-panel">
                                <button class="rd-navbar-toggle" data-rd-navbar-toggle=".rd-navbar-nav-wrap"><span></span></button>
                                <!-- RD Navbar Brand-->
                                <div class="rd-navbar-brand">
            <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?>">
            <div class="brand__name"><img src="<?php echo get_header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php echo bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>


          <div class="rd-navbar-nav-wrap">
             <div class="rd-navbar-main-item">
               <a class="button button-xs button-primary" href="contacts.html">Get a quote</a></div>
                  <!-- RD Navbar Nav-->
              <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'primary-menu','items_wrap'=> '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>')); ?>
            </nav>
            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

I use mamp the latest version, I download the latest version of wordpress but still the same problem, I edit the old theme still the same problem
please do help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Include `get_footer();` as well, and enable debug define('WP_DEBUG', true); in your wp-settings.php and see if any errors come up.

Comment: thanks,  define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config.php yes I did but the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code file privately, You have some extra closing HTML tags in your code. I removed them for you and now it's working fine.